# Multiple mappers write output to a single file

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, mapper

i am new to hadoop and am struck with an issue. I have a use case where i want to run a map only job on a file about 2gb size. I created 4 splits of size 512MB using CombineHiveInputFormat and produced 4 mappers for each split. However when these mappers try to write their output to a single output file, i find some data discrepancies. Is it possible for multiple mappers to write their output to a same file? If so, is there anything that I need to do to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in a *MapReduce* job, mappers does not write to any *HDFS* file. Instead they pass their data to an `IdentityReducer` which will then write the output to a file (Or multiple files in the case of multiple reducers).

Try to set up in your client code:

```
  //...
  conf.setReducerClass(IdentityReducer.class);
  conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```